# How can i get odoo 9 enterprise edition's web interface in odoo 8 community edition?

Tags: enterprise, odoo-8, odoo-9

I have installed  odoo 8 CE in my system, but i wish to use odoo 9 Enterprise Edition's web interface in my odoo 8 Community edition. Thnks.

Answer (score 0):

In your case basically

You want to make the Odoo Entraprice Web Interface in your Odooo 9.0 to your odoo 8.0 community edition.

Before odoo 8.0 or previous version there have no any Odoo versioning feacility for Community as well as Enterprise.
The newly versioning comes at Odoo 9.0 or later version.

**We need to make and purchase our own Enterprise Edition for the following type of source :**

```
1.Windows
2.Ubuntu *Debian
3.RPM
4.Sources
```

You can make some changes into the web as per your need and It will make to feet with the lower version for Odoo 8.0.

You must have to do some customization on web part of Odoo and make the things work for all the development addons of its web interface.

**You can buy the Odoo Enterprise edition using below link:**

https://www.odoo.com/es_ES/page/download

You can fill the meaningful information and make the payment to do purchase from the Odoo server source.

I hope my answer may helpful for you :)